# How to get ethernet channel loading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ethernet

Good afternoon! Collied with specific problem. Help me find decision.

---

**Given**: ftp-server with Debain based OS. Some users downloading files at current moment. Each connection has different downloading speed. Max server uploading speed — 100 Mbit\sec

**Requires**: get channel loading speed across uploading speed. Statistic must be taken each n seconds (using, for example, pattern "Observer"). Result must be in numbers — count of uploading kbit\sec at current moment.

**Question**: how I can get this uploading speed? Maybe, exists method in Java Core libraries or external libraries, which give opportunity to get uploading speed at current moment or it can be realized using another approach?

---

**Possible decision**: only one decision, which I fount — get statistic from console Linux program and just parse it. To call programs can be used method `exec`. But, all programs, which I found is very hard to parse, because they have own "console windows" and work dynamically. I very want to find more suitable variant.

Comment: Why does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: Similar questions had been posted here before, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10471767/1328439

Comment: @JoeC apparently the O.P. is monitoring his ftp server from a java app. I believe the `java` tag is correctly applied here.

Comment: ty Dmitri Chubarov

Comment: @JoeC, Dmitri said correctly. I want to monitore my system.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, how wrote in this answer, file `/proc/net/dev` has **total** statistic, but I need statistic at **current moment**. This method, as I understand it, is designed to obtain average statistics.

Comment: @jww, question about programming. I use concrete programming language and try to find programmatic decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `netdiag` package provide tow useful tools to monitor the network
  : `netwatch` and `netload`

  The `netload` will display every second all the Received /
  Transmitted byte and the total.

  Usage : `netload <interface>`

  The `netwatch` will be helpful to list the remote hosts with the
  transmissed data.
- The `speedometer` command will display a graph of the transferred
  data on the terminal, it can be installed through `apt`. Usage:

  `speedometer -r <interface> -t <interface>`
- the `vnstat` command will display the real-time TX/RX and more.

  `vnstat -l -i <interface>`

The `man vnstat`:

> vnStat  is  a console-based network traffic monitor. It keeps a log of hourly,
>          daily and monthly network traffic for the selected interface(s).  However,  it
>          isn't  a  packet  sniffer. The traffic information is read from the proc(5) or
>          sys filesystems depending on availability. That way vnStat can  be  used  even
>          without root permissions on most systems.
>
> The  implementation  is  divided  into two commands. The purpose of the vnstat
>      command is to provide an interface for querying the traffic information stored
>      in  network  interface  specific  databases  where as the daemon vnstatd(1) is
>      responsible for data retrieval and storage. Although  the  daemon  process  is
>      constantly  running  as  a  service,  it is actually spending most of the time
>      sleeping between data updates.